# sas proc parameter size limit

Tags: sas, proc

I have the following code:

```
proc export
    data=mylib.datain (
        drop=
            first_name mi last_name suffix
            addr_1 addr_2 city
            birth_dt_agg_ind
            sec_birth_dt_agg_act
            sec_first_name_agg_act
            sec_mi_agg_act
            sec_last_name_agg_act
            sec_suffix_agg_act
            ibx_nm_gender_1st_individual_pre
            ibx_nm_gender_2nd_individual_pre
        obs=2
    )
    outfile=stdout
    dbms=csv
;

run;
```

It works fine.  But I don't want multiple fields per line.  For reasons of reading and editing, I want one field per line.  But when I do this, it fails.  Here is the code nicely indented--same non-white-space characters, but it doesn't work:

```
proc export
    data=mylib.datain (
        drop=
            first_name 
            mi 
            last_name suffix
            addr_1 
            addr_2 
            city
            birth_dt_agg_ind
            sec_birth_dt_agg_act
            sec_first_name_agg_act
            sec_mi_agg_act
            sec_last_name_agg_act
            sec_suffix_agg_act
            ibx_nm_gender_1st_individual_pre
            ibx_nm_gender_2nd_individual_pre
        obs=2
    )
    outfile=stdout
    dbms=csv
;

run;
```

I suspect it is because there are more than 256 characters in the "drop=" clause at that point.  Now, I know I can just take out the white space, or use tabs instead of spaces--in this case, because I'm right at the edge.

But in the general case, is there a limit to the number of characters that can be in a parameter to a proc?  Is it 256?  Is there a way around this?  I tried using two different "drop=" parameters, but that didn't work.

Comment: Very strange.  I've never had any issues with parameter lengths.  What error message are you seeing?

Comment: What version of SAS are you on? Are you running this code via %include or batch?

Comment: Are you positive that you didn't introduce invisible characters like 'A0'X or '09'x when you re-formatted the text?

Comment: The message varies depending on how many characters I go over.  It's almost random.  I think it cuts off at some point and depending on that cut off, a strange message happens.

Comment: I did check for invisible characters, thanks for asking.  I can even reproduce it by using the exact same file and just putting a ton of spaces on the indent, so I'm sure I'm just adding spaces to an otherwise working file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a limit on the length of dataset options like `DROP=`. But `PROC EXPORT` is basically an SCL program that SAS wrote. Perhaps the interface to that is what is causing the issue.

Create a view and tell PROC EXPORT to use that.

```
data myview / view=myview ;
  set mylib.datain
    (
      drop=
        first_name
        mi
        last_name suffix
        addr_1
        addr_2
        city
        birth_dt_agg_ind
        sec_birth_dt_agg_act
        sec_first_name_agg_act
        sec_mi_agg_act
        sec_last_name_agg_act
        sec_suffix_agg_act
        ibx_nm_gender_1st_individual_pre
        ibx_nm_gender_2nd_individual_pre
      obs=2
    )
  ;
run;

proc export
  data=myview
  outfile=stdout
  dbms=csv
;
run;
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Works perfectly.